# text button displayed on multiple lines

Tags: css

I have a header button that is displayed on multiple lines.

```
<div class="container">
    <span style="left:32px;">MALISIMMO</span>
    <button  class="btn1" style="left:150px;">Buy</button>
    <button class="btn1" style="left:300px;">About Us Us Us</button>
    <button class="position3" >SIGN IN</button>
</div>
```

See the fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/flamant/09csye6f/31/). About Us Us Us is displayed on three lines. How to display it on one line ?

Comment: you should rethink your layout because using position:absolute isn't a good idea here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `white-space: nowrap`

```
.btn1 {
  border: none;
  background-color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove all of the `position` style rules:

```css
.container {
  height: 65px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.container > *{
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.btn1 {
  border: none;
  background-color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <span style="left:32px;">MALISIMMO</span>
 <button  class="btn1" style="left:150px;">Buy</button>
 <button class="btn1" style="left:300px;">About Us Us Us</button>
 <button class="position3" >SIGN IN</button>

</div>
```